# How to do a 3-table join with aggregate functions and a group by clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I can't figure out how to do a 3-table join with aggregate functions and a group by clause.

I have 3 tables:

| Products |
| --- |
| id |
| ... |

| Sales |
| --- |
| id |
| product_id |
| sale_price |
| ... |

| Punches |
| --- |
| id |
| punchable_id |
| punchable_type |
| ... |

I want to get all of the products data together with its total number of sales, views, (each row in punches table represents a view) and the total revenue from a product.

I have the following query:

```
@products = Product.joins("INNER JOIN sales ON sales.product_id = products.id INNER JOIN punches ON sales.product_id = punches.punchable_id AND punches.punchable_type = 'Product'").group("products.id").select("products.*, SUM(sales.sale_price) as revenue, COUNT(sales.id) as total_sales_count, COUNT(punches.id) as views").distinct
```

However, this is giving me the wrong data for the aggregate functions. The numbers are very high (I think it's summing and counting the rows a bunch of extra times).

When I do the Inner Join query with the `products` table and only one other table (either the `punches` or `sales` table), the data is fine. It blows up whenever I do the 2 joins in one query.

Does anyone know what's wrong with the above and how to properly write the query?

Comment: It will be helpful if you add associations for models

Comment: Also in query try calling 2 separate `joins` method for each table

Answer (score 0):

You should join to punches directly with `products.id = punches.punchable_id ..etc` not via `sales.product_id`